# Turning off Chrome's visual effects

Tags: windows, ubuntu, google-chrome, visual-effects

Is there any way to turn off the visual effects used by Google Chrome?

For example, the tabs slide around smoothly, the scrolling is really smooth, and there is a huge arrow that fades in and out during download.

Reason why I'd like to know is primarily because I want to maximize battery life on my netbook by using less visual effects and, secondly, because I use Chrome on slower systems and would like to maximize the performance and efficiency of Chrome.

This applies mainly to Windows XP, but also Vista, 7 and even (X)Ubuntu 9.10.

**EDIT1:** Oh yes... disabling the attaching/detaching of tabs and turning them into translucent in the process. That's a bit stressful on my slower machines.

Comment: +1. That's also a major issue over RDP on slower connections.

Comment: The scrolling in Chrome is really smooth? That's weird, it's instant for... wait... Well, no. I generally click on the arrows, or better yet, use the arrow keys and page up/down buttons to scroll the page, so it only has to redraw once.

However: If your netbook has an accelerated graphics card... well, nevermind. Do netbooks even have graphics acceleration?

Comment: True, but having a small screen, I use ChiralMotion scrolling most of the time (circular motion), so I'd rather use my scrolling feature but without smooth scroll.

And yes, there is graphics acceleration.

Comment: @Nicholas: all netbooks have at least Intel graphics card, which *provides* graphical acceleration -- but only 2D one. Without it scrolling would be INCREDIBLY slow: try booting in plain VGA/VESA mode to see what I mean.

Comment: Since new Chrome 32.0.1700.102 they now added also animated effect when clicking on any HTML scroll-listbox. I simply can't stand at this, but I don't know how to turn them off. I tried in chrome://flags/ but there seem to be no options to turn off such effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think really the only way to do this would be to get involved with the Chromium project and modify the source.

Comment: Or post a request on one of the Chromium Forums pr project sites. (Not *everyone* is a developer or programmer.)

Comment: @Moshe: Exactly... I am neither.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that might help some,

`chrome://flags/`

that will provide us internal flags used by the browser,

We can refer list and tweak with renderings plugins internal add-ins and many more,

Options like `LCD text antialiasing` or `Overlay Scrollbars` may trick some visual effects..

**Note** it is designed for internal use by chrome only, so use at own risk,
change one by one and restart browser to take effect, so that you can change it back to normal..